# How to get the total network interfaces quota in Azure

Tags: azure, network-interface, azure-cli

Do we have a '`az`' command to get the total and used network interfaces on a specific landscape in azure cloud.

I tried with "`az network nic list`" but it does not display the total and used count.

Regards,

Rohith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such command.

But you could use a script to get total and used count. If you use bash shell, you could use the following example.

```
num=`az network nic list -o table | wc -l`
count=$(( $num - 2 ))
echo $count

az network nic list>test.nic
##if the vic is associated to VM, it will show vm id. if the nic is not associated to VM, it is null
no_use=`cat test.nic |grep "virtualMachine\"\: null"|wc -l`
used_nic=$(( $count - $no_use ))
echo used_nic
```

Comment: This is not giving me the required number..! :( 
Azure console shows different values for Total Network Interfaces.

Comment: @Rohith `az network list-usages --location <location>` the command only get specific location nic count. The example could get the all nics in your subscription.

Comment: @Rohith Also, `az network list-usages --location <location>` could not get the nic attached to VMs.

Comment: I use the command `az network list-usages  --location eastus -o table|grep "Network Interfaces"` I get the same result with my example. If possible, you could try.

Comment: @ Shengbao Shui, i didn't try - as i got the right command the does my job: az network list-usages --location <location>

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

```
az network list-usages --location <location>
```

Comment: `used count` do you mean the nics created in your subscription or nic attached to VMs? If nics created in specific location, this is a correct answer. If you want to know that nic is attached to VM, you could try my example.